# Run Java Jar as Service via Ansible on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, service, jar, ansible, devops

What is the best approach to run a standalone .jar as a service via Ansible?

I need run metabase.jar via ansible on an Ubuntu EC2 host.

Should I daemonize it? Is there any recommended method or library?

Ideally I would like to manage the state via the Ansible handlers if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending upon the init system of your underlying box (init.d or systemctl) there are two approaches.

---

**init.d**

With ansible you can create a symlink of your application jar under

```
/etc/init.d/<your_service_name>
```

You can then use ansible's service module to manage the state of the 
service

```
 - service:
    name: <your_service_name>
    state: restarted
```

More info: [Ansible service module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html)

---

**systemctl**

If your init method is systemd you will have to create a very simple Unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=<Description>

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/<your_app>.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Copy the unit file to

```
/etc/systemd/service/<your_unit_file>.service
```

Then you can use ansible's systemd module to manage the state of the service

```
- name: Start Service
  systemd:
    name: <your service name>
    state: started
```

More info: [Ansible systemd module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/systemd_module.html)

Comment: the service file must be placed in ```/etc/systemd/system``` though, but otherwise correct

Comment: Changed the path in my answer. Great it worked for you.

Comment: this worked for me changing the `ExecStart` line to `/path/to/java -jar /path/to/<your app>.jar`

Comment: How can I pass arguments in the .service file?